# Why is the <ul> rendering twice?

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

So I am collecting some data from the firebase firestore and i wanted to display it. I managed to get the data through the .get() method. But for some reason the data is being displayed twice. This is React JS app 
**JS**

```
    function renderList(doc) {
        let li = document.createElement('li')
        let name = document.createElement('span')
        let bloodGroup = document.createElement('span')
        let district = document.createElement('span')
        let phoneNumber = document.createElement('span')
        let vaccineDays = document.createElement('span')

        li.setAttribute('data-id', doc.id)
        name.textContent = doc.data().name;
        bloodGroup.textContent = doc.data().bloodGroup;
        district.textContent = doc.data().district;
        phoneNumber.textContent = doc.data().phoneNumber
        vaccineDays.textContent = doc.data().vaccineDays

        li.appendChild(name);
        li.appendChild(bloodGroup);
        li.appendChild(district);
        li.appendChild(vaccineDays);

        document.getElementById("donator-list").appendChild(li)


    }
    db.collection("donators").get().then((snapshot) => {
        snapshot.docs.forEach(doc => {
            renderList(doc)
        })
    })
    return (
        <div>
            <ul id="donator-list">

            </ul>
        </div>
    )
```

Comment: In React, you shouldn't really be appending anything to the HTML manually, you would be better off building an array and mapping it into elements in the return statement (Or returning an array of JSX elements from the `renderList` itself)

Comment: Can you elaborate? @DBS

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's likely that what is happening here is: React is rendering multiple times (this is expected) but on each render, you are manually adding to the DOM.

The normal React way to do this would be:

- Make the call (Probably inside an [Effect](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.htm))
- Store the data you need in [React State](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html)
- In the returned JSX, build the structure you would like to appear.

It's a little difficult to show exactly as your example doesn't have the entire component, but this is roughly what I would expect it to look like:

```
const [docs, setDocs] = useState([])

/* 
* I would expect this call to be made inside an effect,
* so you don't do it every render, but I don't know what you 
* would want to trigger it, so it's running on first load.
*/
useEffect(() => {
    db.collection("donators").get().then((snapshot) => {
        setDocs(snapshot.docs)
    })
}, [])

return (
    <div>
        <ul id="donator-list">
            { docs.map(doc => 
                 <li>
                     <span>{ doc.data().name }</span>
                     { /* Add your other spans here */ }
                 </li>
            )}
        </ul>
    </div>
)
```

Comment: Ahh I Understand Now. Thank You!